# How to fire native mobile selector wheel on mobile devices in jQueryUI Selectmenu

Tags: android, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am using the jQueryUI SelectMenu, to style our dropdowns.
However, I need to show the native scroll wheel interface when on mobile, as the menu's are just too long on mobile.

Menu: http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Is there a way to have the jQueryUI interface on desktop, but on tablets and mobiles, upon clicking the menu, the native device selector wheel appears on the screen?

I have searched and searched, but can't find an answer for this. Already checked previous questions on SO, but couldnt find it. Unless I was using the wrong keywords.

Also, noticed that in searches, jQueryMobile selectmenu came up, but this is something different. Hope I  dont have to switch to this, as it would require a lot of rework.

Any advise? Please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no support for native menu on mobile devices. It would introduce issues with the callback events, etc. as it's not possible to hook in native menu events (open, close, etc.).

I've implemented an extension to enable native menus but it's a little outdated. Anyway, it should give you an idea and probably fits your needs. Please note that the callbacks events won't work when using the native menu.

https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui-extensions/tree/selectmenu

Comment: Thanks Felix for the reply. When you say outdated, what do you mean, as the last update you made to the code was 4 days ago?

Comment: The update was pushed four days ago but was implemented a few month ago. So I'm not sure if it needs an update to work with the latest Selectmenu Widget version. Sorry for not making this more clear.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification. btw, can you let me know what the difference is between jQueryUI Selectmenu and the jQuery Mobile selectmenu? As theirs has a pseudo native dropdown popup doesnt it? What are the cons of moving over to theirs?

Comment: Sure. The jQuery Team plans to merge these projects but that's a long time goal. 

Mobile is able to display a native menu but lacks most callback events due to technical limitation. The accessibility of UI Selectmenu should be much better for the same reasons.

Another main difference is the "custom" menu: UI works like a stylable proxy for a native select while Mobile works more like a mobile page navigation (and actually uses that Mobile component). Mobile Selectmenu has more dependencies when used with the custom menu.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! Ah ok, so for our use, where we want a select box with no background, no border, and a custom arrow on the right hand size, with custom styled dropdown look, it would be better to use UI SelectMenu as a base, and your plugin for mobile?

Comment: I was thinking maybe to customize the UI selectmenu on mobile media query, so that it has bigger text and fits the screen. Ideally, you would want the menu to be about 90% width/height of the screen and thus end up being a popup in a way anyway. (Reason for this is that our users are complaining that its hard to select the jQuery UI options on mobile, the button and the menu are too small.

Comment: For a website I would use UI in addition with the extension (which is a proof of concept by the way, needs testing!). I use jQuery Mobile for apps but not for websites, but that's just my opinion. I strongly recommend that a mobile user should be able to use the native OS dialog when using a select.